# Tayors series exansion of $(1 - x )^n$ where $0<x<1$ and $n \ge 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I want to find Taylor's series or Maclaurin's series expansion of the following.

$$(1 - x)^n  \ \text{ where }\  \ 0 < x < 1  \text{ and }\ n \ge 0$$

will it be same as that for

$$(1 + x)^n  \ \text{ where } \ -1 < x < 1\  \text{ and } \ n >= 0 $$

with sign reversed or something like that ? please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that
$$
(1+w)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}w^n,\qquad -1<w<1.
$$
To get a series for $(1-x)^n$, you need only realize that $(1-x)^n=(1+(-x))^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have to replace x with -x, you only have to change the signs so that they are alternating.